# java 8 can I use accumulator when dynamically chaining

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When working on the [Mars Rover kata](https://kata-log.rocks/mars-rover-kata) in java 8, we set out to try and go for max immutability and we ended up in this corner :

```
rover = rover.move(new Commands("RFF");
```

...

```
class Rover{
...
    public Rover move(Commands commands) {
        Rover rover = this; //ignore IDE concurrency warning as Rover is designed to being immutable
        for (Command command: commands) rover = rover.move(command);
        return rover;
    }
```

We thought it should be possible to practice on the Streams syntax here, but we couldn't figure it out:

```
return commands.foreach((this, rover, command) -> rover = rover.move(command)).getAccumulator();
```

With 'this' as the seed, rover as accumulator, command as each command in the Array.  I though I had done this kind of thing in C# during a functional programming training.  But not sure :)

Comment: What you seem to be looking for closely resembles a custom `Collector` for you to collect the output. It might very well be implemented by the `reduce` but that depends upon the definition of `commands.asArray` and `rover.move`. Also, did you mean to use different classes `Command` and `Commands`?

Comment: There is no “power of Streams” that justifies changing the simple, straight-forward loop of your example to something more complicated. If you want to improve the code, make  `Commands` implement `Iterable<Command>`, to get rid of the necessity to copy the contents into an array for each iteration.

Comment: the power in this case was in 'exploring' how they work during a kata.  so we can understand their syntax and usage.  
the power also resides in learning to think more functional, and reduce the nr of assignments (mutability) in the code.

Comment: @Naman : you're right !  we updated the code immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator you are looking for is [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). You could use it like so:

```java
return commands.reduce(this, Rover::move, (r1, r2) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); });
```

The unfortunate part is that `reduce` requires you to handle combination of values, which your system cannot do. So you must throw an exception in that case. I think your current loop solution is just fine, and as other comments have said, switching to streams "just because" is not advised.

Comment: It works perfectly - but I don't get how completely:
  Rover::Move is a reference to the function to combine 
               apply(r2 = r1.Move(c[0])
               .andThen(r2 = r2.Move(c[1]) 'all the way down the stream
              returning in the end the value of the last r2
  but what does the combiner do then, and why does it need to throw an exception...

Answer (score 0):

for those interested: our current best effort resulted in the following:

```
class Rover {

    public Rover move(Commands commands) {
        BiFunction<Rover, ? super Command, Rover> action = Rover::move;
        return commands.executeAccumulativelyStartingWith(this, action);
    }

    public Rover move(Command command){
        return command.executeOn(this);
    }
    ...
}

class Commands {

    public Rover executeAccumulativelyStartingWith(Rover initialRover, BiFunction<Rover, ? super Command, Rover> action) {
        BinaryOperator<Rover> combiner = (r1, r2) -> {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();};
        return commands.stream().reduce(initialRover, action, combiner);
    }
    ...
}
```